# Looping through arrays in VBA

Tags: arrays, vba, excel, loops, max

I am trying to loop through an array that I have, First I create my array from spreadsheet data that begins in row 2, column 2 (roughly 1000 rows x 100 columns). After defining my array I want to treat each column as a separate data set, find the max value and the row number of the max value, then store each in separate arrays. When I run this code it returns a column of 0 values. It does not give any errors but it is obviously not working, any suggestions?

```
Public Maxindex() As Long

Public MaxVal() As Double

Sub ArrayOptimized()
'Uses arrays to call data from the sheet once then process it

    Dim dataset() As Variant
    Dim rows As Long
    Dim columns As Integer

    ReDim Maxindex(100)
    ReDim MaxVal(100)
    MaxVal(1) = 1

    rows = ShData.Cells(ShData.rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row
    columns = ShData.Cells(1, ShData.columns.Count).End(xlToLeft).Column
    ReDim dataset(2 To rows, 2 To columns)
    dataset = ShData.Range(ShData.Cells(2, 2), ShData.Cells(rows, columns))
   'Check to sheet

    Sheet1.Range(Sheet1.Cells(1, 1), Sheet1.Cells(rows, columns)) = dataset


    For i = LBound(dataset, 2) To UBound(dataset, 2)

        For j = LBound(dataset, 1) To UBound(dataset, 1)
            If dataset(j, i) > MaxVal(i) Then
            MaxVal(i) = dataset(j, i)
            'Returns row index number in array for max val
            Maxindex(i) = j
            End If

        Next j

    Next i

    Sheet2.Range(Sheet2.Cells(1, 1), Sheet2.Cells(columns, 1)) = Maxindex

End Sub
```

Comment: I was writing an answer but Tim beat me to it. You are getting the first element of the zero-based array of maximums as you only started supplying values at index 1; the lbound of dataset. Further, the `ReDim dataset(2 To rows, 2 To columns)` does nothing since in the very next line you assign values (by implicit default) to dataset.

Comment: Yep. Beat me to it also - I'd consider `ReDim Maxindex(1 To columns)` and `ReDim MaxVal(1 To columns)` instead of a fixed value too.

Comment: @Jeeped So I don't need to sepcify the array size before assigning values?

Comment: No you are redim'ming it to a 2-D array as you assign the values from the cells. About the 1-D array: you could use `redim Maxindex(LBound(dataset, 2) To UBound(dataset, 2))` and then you wouldn't have to adjust `i` to use it as the index of maxindex. e.g. `Maxindex(i) = j` instead of `Maxindex(i - 1) = j`; you could use `redim Maxindex(LBound(dataset, 2) To UBound(dataset, 2), 1 to 1)` and then you wouldn't have to transpose it.

Comment: @jeeped Waht does the "1 to 1" do in "redim Maxindex(LBound(dataset, 2) To UBound(dataset, 2), 1 to 1)"?

Comment: Well, it makes it a 2D array with the same number of 'rows' as dataset has 'columns' but 1 'column' wide of course. That's exactly what you want to put back on the worksheet.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

By default Excel wants to place a 1-D array on the sheet in a *row*, not in a column, so you get the first element of the array in each cell when you try to put it in a column.

All values are zero becuase your 1-d array is zero-based and you didn't populate that slot in your loop.

You can use transpose to "flip" your array into a column:

```
Sheet2.Range(Sheet2.Cells(1, 1), Sheet2.Cells(columns, 1)) = _
     Application.Transpose(Maxindex)
```